# What is the best way to sort a specific range on one sheet in a worksheet?

Tags: sorting, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am trying to auto sort a small range of data on one specific sheet within another (massive) workbook. I want the range (P27:R40) to sort descendingly every time the sheet is edited, but none of the code I've used has worked. Do I have to include the worksheet name as well as the specific sheet name? (To clarify, I am trying to edit a sheet called "May20" within a worksheet named "Rankings" -- am I missing something here?) Here is the code I've tried using, but it doesn't run upon editing.

```
function onEdit(e) {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
 var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("May20")
  var range = sheet.getRange("P27:R40");

 // Sorts by the values in column 18 (R)
 range.sort({column: 18, ascending: false});

}
```

Comment: I copied your code, made a sheet called May20 and edited something in range P27:R40. Seems to work fine, exactly like you coded it. Could you perhaps share us in your spreadsheet?

Comment: Unfortunately, there is some privileged data in the spreadsheet (it's for work) so I can't share it. I am getting the error message "TypeError: Cannot read property 'getSheetByName' of null (line 3, file "Code")"

Comment: Looking at the error message it seems that there is no ActiveSpreadSheet instance, it can happen when the script is written as stand alone project and is not bound to any SpreadSheet. Can you confirm that the App Script was created after opening it from Spreadsheet tools itself?

Comment: How about changing the script into an regular script and run the debugger trough it?

Comment: Fixed -- thank you so much!

Comment: @sydmcoleman Questions should have answers. Would you consider posting an answer explaining what issue were you having and how you solved that?